# Монетизация приложения с помощью AdMob

Tags: android, монетизация, admob

Вроде как рекламный баннер правильно настроил, попросил друзей по разу кликнуть для проверки - в итоге появилось 10 центов. Висели они пару дней, потом вдруг они начали вычитаться.

Стало 6 центов, на следующий день - 4 цента, потом - 2. Неделю держалось 2 цента, теперь - 1.

Т.е. доход в 10 раз уменьшили. Клики и деньги просто обнуляются со временем.

Что происходит? Нужно жаловаться или что?

Comment: Санкции (:

Comment: Но я же с Украины!

Comment: @romanzi двойная политика. )
______
А если по существу, вы итоговый баланс смотрите? Уверены? Может, вы данные по датам смотрите?

Comment: У меня в истории транзакций есть строчка "Недопустимый трафик: Приложения AdMob: объявления AdWords -0.04". И да, лучше не жаловаться, они страшные люди), банят по любому поводу!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гугл своим алгоритмом часто убивает "ложные клики".
Если соберешься жаловаться - аккуратней. Некоторых банили после жалобы. И еще: перед тем как жаловаться, почитай те соглашения, что подписал. 
Сдается мне, что жаловаться ты не сможешь (за такую фразу забанят, запрещено просить нажимать на рекламу).

Answer (score 2):

Не пиши жалобу. Просто жди реальных кликов. Просить пользователей кликать - бан. Сам будешь кликать - бан. Будешь сам смотреть рекламу - бан.

Лучше улучшай приложение. Толку будет больше. И главное - НЕ СПЕШИ ! Сразу тысячи долларов в день получать не будешь. Придется идти к этому. По своему опыту сужу. Я поспешил, поставил реальный баннер вместо тестового. Через три дня получил бан навсегда за накрутку кликов и просмотров. Хотя я хотел просто проверить работоспособность кода.

Удачи!

UPD 1: А центы могут падать не из-за того, что у тебя гугл забирает деньги, а это всего лишь счетчик эффективности рекламы показывает твой приблизительный доход. 
То есть изначально друзья накликали, бот решил, что народ интересуется и повысил значение счетчика, потом клики пропали - счетчик обнулился.

Почитай:

- [Это](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2615875?hl=ru) - гугл источник
- И [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/163339/) - хабрахабр статья